# Unrecoverable crashes

Tags: 20.04, crash

I've been having issues with ubuntu crashing unrecoverably. I've had the issue on my laptop when running supercollider at the same time as youtube, and now on my new desktop computer when using google maps. I can't figure out what the cause is - the mouse will still work but the screen and keyboard will be completely unresponsive. can't `ctrl`+`alt`+`f1` to get into the shell, reset `xfce`, or anything. REISUB still works, and I can still hear audio if I'm on a phone call of any kind (google meet, zoom, etc).

laptop was intel core i7 with nvidia mobile video card, don't remember the make exactly.
desktop:Ubuntu (Ubuntu Studio) 20.04 /
AMD Ryzen 7 3700X /
Radeon 5700 XT /
64 GB RAM. Has anyone else been having hard crashes like this? I was hoping I could see less of these by using ubuntu, not more.

```
ls -al /var/crash
total 17776
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie     4096 Jun 10 19:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root         4096 May 25 22:25 ..
-rw-------  1 root whoopsie   142836 Jun  7 14:48 amdgpu-pro-pin.0.crash
-rw-r-----  1 ino  whoopsie 10386868 Jun 10 19:37 _opt_Signal_signal-desktop.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 ino  whoopsie    69067 Jun 10 12:49 _usr_bin_blueman-tray.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 ino  whoopsie  7591345 Jun 10 13:56 _usr_bin_emacs-gtk.1000.crash

free -h:
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           62Gi       4.5Gi        53Gi       736Mi       4.9Gi        56Gi
Swap:          61Gi          0B        61Gi

sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 10

sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
1104
```

Custom build, motherboard is ASUS AMD AM4 PRO WS X570-ACE ATX Workstation.

Comment: Could be hardware issues. Watch kernel messages (`dmesg -w` for continuous display). Many red messages may point to some hardware failing.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash` and `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the make/model of your computer or motherboard (if custom build).

Comment: @vanadium no red, no errors. hardware is all new, this pc was built less than a month ago (not that hardware can't still fail)

Comment: @heynnema did the edit!

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema it crashed again last night, again while using google maps in firefox.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash` again. Also, did you ever run memtest? I think it's about time. Understand that it'll take a lot of time, unless it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**BIOS**

`ASUS` AMD AM4 `PRO WS X570-ACE` ATX Workstation

You have BIOS 1104.

There's a newer BIOS available, 1302, dated 2/19/2020 and can be downloaded [here](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Pro-WS-X570-ACE/HelpDesk_BIOS/) or [here](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Pro-WS-X570-ACE/HelpDesk_Download/).

**Note**: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your motherboard.

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**Memtest**

Because of the large amount of RAM, and the kind of crashes that you're seeing, if memory tests have never been run, go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**Swap**

With 64G RAM, you have excessive swap, unless you're hibernating, at 61G. Reduce it to 4G. Depending on if you're using a swap partition or a /swapfile, the method to reduce is different.

Assuming that you're using a /swapfile...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 64G RAM and 4G swap
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

Add this line to /etc/fstab, if it's not already there...

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0
```

**vm.swappiness**

vm.swappiness = 10 is really unnecessary.

Set vm.swappiness=60 (based on 64G RAM and 4G SWAP), this way...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/sysctl.conf` # edit this file

Search for an existing `vm.swappiness=` entry...

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> vm.swappiness

- If found, **edit** it to say `vm.swappiness=60`
- If not found, **add** `vm.swappiness=60` at the end of the file

Save your edits and quit gedit

`sudo sysctl -p`

Comment: Looks like it is working so far, I will update if it crashes again. Thank you so much!